# java_home issue on macbook 12.3.1 Monterey (M1)

Tags: java, macos, java-11, apple-m1, java-home

java_home is not setup, Unable to locate a Java Runtime on Mac M1  (12.3.1 - Monterey)

openjdk is installed:

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0, mixed mode)

/usr/libexec/java_home
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

I setup `JAVA_HOME` already in the profiles :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.15/libexec/openjdk.j/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `java_home` only looks for runtimes in 2 locations:

- `$HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

A symlink works but will need to be kept up-to-date as homebrew upgrades:

```
$ ln -sf /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.15/libexec/openjdk.jdk ~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk11
```

It then appears in the list in its original location:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    18.0.1.1 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 18.0.1.1" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.15 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 11.0.15" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.15/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_332 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 8.62.0.19" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```